# Make the right visualization for R plotly scatterplot

Tags: r, graph, plotly, r-plotly

I have a dataframe:

```
x = data.frame(metrics=c("type1", "type1", "type1","type1", "type1", "type1", "orders", "orders", "orders","orders", "orders", "orders", "mean","mean","mean","mean","mean","mean"), hr=c(6,7,8,6,7,8,6,7,8,6,7,8,6,7,8,6,7,8), actual=c(14,20,34,22,24,27,56,12,34,11,15,45,56,78,89,111,123,156), time_pos=c("today", "yesterday", "today", "yesterday", "today", "yesterday"))
```

Here is a code to draw scatterplot subplots:

```
library(plotly)

plot <- function(df) {
  .pal <- RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(3, "Set2")[c(1, 3)]
  subplotList <- list()
  for(metric in unique(df$metrics)){
    showlegend <- metric == unique(df$metrics)[1]
    subplotList[[metric]] <- df[df$metrics == metric,] %>%
      plot_ly(
        x = ~ hr,
        y = ~ actual,
        color = ~ time_pos,
        colors = .pal,
        legendgroup = ~time_pos,
        showlegend = showlegend,
        hoverinfo = "text",
        hovertemplate = paste(
          "<b>%{text}</b><br>",
          "%{xaxis.title.text}: %{x:+.1f}<br>",
          "%{yaxis.title.text}: %{y:+.1f}<br>",
          "<extra></extra>"
        ),
        type = "scatter",
        mode = "lines+markers",
        marker = list(
          size = 7,
          color = "white",
          line = list(width = 1.5)
        ),
        width = 700,
        height = 620
      ) %>% 
      add_annotations(
        text = ~metrics,
        x = 0.5,
        y = 1,
        yref = "paper",
        xref = "paper",
        xanchor = "center",
        yanchor = "bottom",
        showarrow = FALSE,
        font = list(size = 15)
      ) %>% 
      layout(autosize = T, legend = list(font = list(size = 8)))
  }
  subplot(subplotList, nrows = length(subplotList), margin = 0.05)
}

plot(x)
```

Here is a graph:

[image]

As you see, for example in first subplot, first marker is connected to both second and third markers, though it must be connected only with second marker. The same thing happens with second subplot. How could i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

That can be achived by ordering the data.frame accordingly:

```
library(plotly)

x = data.frame(metrics=c("type1", "type1", "type1","type1", "type1", "type1", "orders", "orders", "orders","orders", "orders", "orders", "mean","mean","mean","mean","mean","mean"), hr=c(6,7,8,6,7,8,6,7,8,6,7,8,6,7,8,6,7,8), actual=c(14,20,34,22,24,27,56,12,34,11,15,45,56,78,89,111,123,156), time_pos=c("today", "yesterday", "today", "yesterday", "today", "yesterday"))
x <- x[order(x$hr),]

plot <- function(df) {
  .pal <- RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(3, "Set2")[c(1, 3)]
  subplotList <- list()
  for(metric in unique(df$metrics)){
    showlegend <- metric == unique(df$metrics)[1]
    subplotList[[metric]] <- df[df$metrics == metric,] %>%
      plot_ly(
        x = ~ hr,
        y = ~ actual,
        color = ~ time_pos,
        colors = .pal,
        legendgroup = ~time_pos,
        showlegend = showlegend,
        hoverinfo = "text",
        hovertemplate = paste(
          "<b>%{text}</b><br>",
          "%{xaxis.title.text}: %{x:+.1f}<br>",
          "%{yaxis.title.text}: %{y:+.1f}<br>",
          "<extra></extra>"
        ),
        type = "scatter",
        mode = "lines+markers",
        marker = list(
          size = 7,
          color = "white",
          line = list(width = 1.5)
        ),
        width = 700,
        height = 620
      ) %>% 
      add_annotations(
        text = ~metrics,
        x = 0.5,
        y = 1,
        yref = "paper",
        xref = "paper",
        xanchor = "center",
        yanchor = "bottom",
        showarrow = FALSE,
        font = list(size = 15)
      ) %>% 
      layout(autosize = T, legend = list(font = list(size = 8)))
  }
  subplot(subplotList, nrows = length(subplotList), margin = 0.05)
}

plot(x)
```

[image: result]